# objc_msgSend() dispatch table

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to clear some clutter in my mind to understand objc_msgSend().
Kindly be generous enough to give details answers please. :)

Here is my understand from Apple Doc.

> When a message is sent to an object, the messaging function follows
>   the object's isa pointer to the class structure where it looks up the
>   method selector in the dispatch table. If it cant find the selector
>   there, objc_msgSend() follows the pointer to the supperclass (HERE is
>   confusion) and tries to climb the class hierarchy.

Here, does the superclass get memory allocated and isa pointer available for that superclass? Does the above quote says that?

Comment: It says nothing about allocation, and every object has an isa pointer, so it's unclear which isa you're talking about here. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: you can read the [source code](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h#L303)

Comment: @Chuck this needs some clarification imho, every object has a class (which is a simple struct), and every class has an isa pointer.

Comment: @Chuck: If I have 4 super classes in hierarchy to my class, and when my 5th class is instantiated, does the memory for 4 above classes be allocated or, as they become PART of my 5th class, only as the member variables of the 5th class be instantiated?   If the 4 above classes also get instantiated, 4 isa pointers should be instiated, right?

Comment: @Chuck not every object has an isa "pointer". Tagged objects, and on ARM64 the isa variable **is not a pointer**, it simply doesn't exist. You should always use `object_getClass` to get the class of an object, and NEVER rely on the isa pointer.

Comment: @Chandu: That doesn't really have anything to do with the passage you quoted. I think maybe you're confusing a class's isa with its instances' isas. Each class has an isa, so there is one isa for each class, but the instance itself only has one.

Comment: @Chuck: Final question. If every question has one isa and in an inheritance hierarchy A>B>C>D>E  ... if class E gets instantiated, do all the A,B,C,D classes' isa pointers get instantiated?

Comment: @Chandu: You don't instantiate an isa pointer. That's not a thing. The instance will have its isa pointer set to class E, because that's the object's class.

Comment: @Chuck: Sorry. I never said I instantiate it on my own. Does it get instantiated?   Question is simple: if I instantiate a child class, does the parent's isa pointed be allocated memory or not please?

Comment: @Chandu: You still seem to be confusing a class and an instance of that class. That class's isa will already be occupying memory in the data structure representing the class. Any instances you create will have their own isa, because an instance of a class is not the same thing as that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were look at the pre-ObjC-2.0 declaration of NSObject, you'd see:

```
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
    Class isa;
}
```

Where Class is:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

And objc_class is:

```
struct objc_class {         
    struct objc_class *isa; 
    struct objc_class *super_class; 
    const char *name;       
    long version;
    long info;
    long instance_size;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars;
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists;
    struct objc_cache *cache;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols;
};
```

Thus, that `isa` pointer -- the first field in `NSObject`, but also the first field in every subclass -- is a pointer to that `objc_class` structure.   The rest of the structure describes the details of that class.   That `super_class` field points to the `objc_class` structure that describes the superclass.

When `objc_msgSend()` tries to dispatch a method to, say, an `NSMutableString`, it first looks through the method list of the `objc_class` describing an `NSMutableString` instance.  If it doesn't find the method, it looks at the `super_class` structure and searches there.  If it can't find it there it then looks in the `super_class`'s `super_class`.

I.e. the `super_class` pointer in the structure pointed to by the `isa` of any given class is a linked list up the class hierarchy all the way to `NSObject` (usually).  If the `super_class` field is empty, that'd be a root class.

Memory allocation is, more or less, done in a similar fashion.   The `instance_size` field of the instance specifies the size of the instance and, thus, the amount of memory to be allocated.

More or less.   All of those structures are now opaque.  As Richard Ross III said in the comments **you must use the introspection functions to get at the contents of these structures**.   This allows Apple to change the implementation details without requiring everything to be recompiled.