# Error when using "setValue: forKey:" on an NSString's isa pointer then calling [string class]

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, objective-c-runtime

Heres's what I've got as to error.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_trap():
0x14c13f4:  pushl  %ebp
0x14c13f5:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x14c13f7:  ud2
```

So basically I'm trying to understand How `NSString` works and trying to find a way to change the pointer that points to "real (char *) string" which is said to be a constant.

So, I found there is a pointer called isa which points to (`__NSCFConstantString *`).
It led me to think that if I change that pointer then I could change the string.

The code I tried was this:

```
NSString *st3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hihi"];
[st3 setValue:@"change" forKey:@"isa"];
```

And, the result showing that

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

It seems changed but it changed every `NSString` object that has @"hihi" string.

And then what I did was **[st3 class]** hoping it will give the `isa` pointer then I got that error message posted on the top.

Could you anyone explain what's going on and why it behaves like this?
And, it there any way to intern (i'm not so sure about the term) like in Java?

Please avoid saying just use "NSMutableString" I'm just trying to figure it out seeing there might be some way to do it.

Comment: oh no please don't play with `isa` without knowing what are you doing. if you want to learn how to change class of object use [`object_setClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setClass)

Comment: Even if you change the class, the object's internal layout then won't match what the new class expects. So, you're likely to just cause crashes. And immutable strings may be shared even when you think they should be independent copies. So, you're not going to be able to reliably limit your changes to a single instance. Finally, you changed the class of an object, but rather than changing it to a different class, you changed it to a string?!? `@"changed"` is not a class, so it isn't suitable for the `isa` pointer (even if it were wise to modify that).

Comment: `cStringUsingEncoding:` may actually give you a pointer to the const char* buffer in NSString, but there's no reason it has to.  And if it does, and you change the data at that memory location, there's no reason the compiler has to use that data it in the code you expect it to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use `NSMutableString`;  mutability is why it exists. ;)

`NSString` is constant.  Not just "wraps a `const char *`" constant, but "no, really, this thing is immutable and the storage details are entirely opaque to you".

In fact, an `__NSCFConstantString` isn't even stored on the heap at all;  there will be no `malloc`d chunk of memory you can muck with.   Such strings are generated by the compiler and the linker lays them down in a chunk of memory that will be read in at runtime and stored on read-only pages of memory.

But not even the results of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d World", 42]` will have storage in a chunk of uniquely allocated `malloc()`d memory just for the string buffer.  *Most likely* (but maybe not -- it is an opaque implementation detail), the mechanism for constructing the formatted string will yield an object whose size will be the minimum instance size for whatever private subclass of `NSString` (see class clusters) is most appropriate + however many bytes are needed to store the string data itself.

While you could potentially find the actual bytes in memory and muck with them directly, that would be a gross violation of encapsulation and utterly useless in a real program.

Note that the `isa` you are mucking with is an instance variable of `NSObject`.  It is a pointer to the Class object of the instance.   It is not necessarily constant, but you really shouldn't muck with it, either.

For more information on the `isa` and why you are seeing that particular crash when you stuck an `NSString` instance into the `isa` slot, my answer to this question may be helpful (maybe):

[objc_msgSend() dispatch table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352289/objc-msgsend-dispatch-table/23355551#23355551)

BTW:  Love the question -- while you are going down a path that is completely at odds with OO programming and the Foundation, mucking about with the innards and wildly breaking things is a fantastic way to learn!  Don't let the down voters get you...well...down, if they should appear.

Comment: Did you mean to say "`isa` ... is **not** an instance variable"?

Comment: @KenThomases nope, `isa` is the one and only instance variable declared by the `NSObject` class.

Comment: @bbum Thank you for the last sentence sir that would help me and cheer me up a lot.